# Cambiar puertos de un SNMP

Tags: linux

buen día

En éste momento me encuentro realizando una configuración por Linux para ejecutar un SNMP bajo el servicio llamado "snmpd"... Sin embargo tenemos un proceso también SNMP que corre bajo un servicio llamado "snmpserverd" el cual ya está ocupando el puerto 161 y 162.

¿Es posible configurar el servicio "snmpd" para que corra sobre algún otro puerto disponible que yo le indique?

Gracias.

Comment: Revisa esto https://superuser.com/questions/986420/how-to-set-up-snmpd-to-listen-on-an-alternative-port-other-than-161

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Funcionó.